# Covering the natural numbers with sequences?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I have got the following question:

Can you cover $\mathbb{N}$ with **finite** amount of arithmetic, **disjunct** sequences(their difference can't be the same, and $d>1$)?

The answer for **countable** amount was **yes**, since we have an example for that: $$\{2n, 4n+1,8n-1,\cdots \}$$
which are of the form $2^kn+u_k$ with $u_k$ is the residue closest to $0$ which has not been previously covered (thanks for the answer), but how about if we can only use **finite** amount?

My guess is no, but I just can't prove why not. :)

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for are "covering systems" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system).  The idea is that you have sets of congruence classes so that every natural number is in one of the congruence classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're precisely searching for a disjoint, distinct [covering system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system).

[Mirsky-Newman theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system#Mirsky.E2.80.93Newman_theorem) is a theorem that says there is no such system.

Comment: Where can I find a proof? :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237909/understanding-a-proof-of-the-davenport-rado-mirsky-newman-theorem Is this connected?

Comment: @Atvin Yes. It proves that if a covering system is disjoint, then there must exist a pair of equal moduli, so the covering system can't be distinct.

Comment: My answer considers $\mathbb Z$ instead of $\mathbb N$.